# postgresql query view : for each author, list their total number of co-author

Tags: sql, postgresql

[sample data and expected result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FLsRi.png)
trying to create query for counting total number of co-authors for each author.

my existing database table will have
2 columns of bookid and its respective authors
each bookid may have more than one authors
and each author may write more than one book.

I want to create a view with 
2 columns of authors name and total number of co-authors

for example if book1 have author1,author2,author3 and book2 have author1,author2,author4, then author 1 will have total number of co-author of 3

note not to double count the same author.

still new with this, tried to write it as a table but was a mess.
thanks!

**Sample data:**

([db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=eb795e8659620dbaf3892d9bdf7f9f17))

```
person_id   person_name   book_id
2           B             1
3           C             2
4           D             2
5           E             2
3           C             3
4           D             3
6           F             3
4           D             4
8           H             4
9           I             4
10          J             4
```

**Expected result:**

```
person_name   coauthors
B             0
C             3
D             6
E             2
F             2
H             3
I             3
J             3
```

ps: I have approximately 2000+ rows of authors and bookid

Comment: Please add some sample data and expected output. It sounds like a bad table design but I could be wrong. Maybe I didn't understand what your tables look like and what you are expecting.

Comment: hi added a picture cant embed it so please click the link to get the picture

Comment: please do not use images as sample data. Because it is not possible to copy the data for those who would answer and need something to play with. I added the raw data for you this time.

Comment: sorry i didnt know how, i will look at that next time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=1c0efc695e98e2fcff3561b2f5c5c181)

```
SELECT 
    a.person_name, 
    count(distinct b.person_id) - 1 as coauthors 
FROM authors a 
INNER JOIN authors b 
ON a.book_id = b.book_id
GROUP BY a.person_id, a.person_name
ORDER BY a.person_name
```

The `INNER JOIN` against the table itself on their `book_id`s creates rows where each author of a certain book is associated to each other. For example for `book_id = 2` it creates the pairs

```
(C, C),
(C, D),
(C, E),
(D, C),
(D, D),
(D, E),
(E, C),
(E, D),
(E, E)
```

This is done for every `book_id`. Now we are able to `GROUP` by author's ID (`person_id`), which gives for example for `D`: `(C, D, E)` (and all other coauthors from other books).

Because for example the aggregate for `D` and all its books look like `(C, D, E, C, D, F, D, H, I, J)` we have to filter out every doubled values. This is what `DISTINCT` does.

Now it looks like `(C, D, E, F, H, I, J)` which makes a count of `7`. Finally we do not want to count the author itself. This is why we substract `1` in the end.

---

*Notice*: If the given table is your real table I would recommend to normalize it. You should have two separated tables: One for the author's details and one for the association to their books. Imagine that you might want to hold the authors' full names (maybe in two columns), their birthdays and many other data. It wouldn't be a good idea to repeat all these data for every book they wrote. Just combine their IDs with the book IDs.

Comment: wow this is really good, so short but did it, i have been stuck since this morning, i was thinking whether i needed a function or aggresion, created bunch of tables(useless). thanks heaps

Comment: the explanation!  you are such a good man. yeah its not the actual real table, it was in separate table, this is a view I made, where I am stuck, but I thought this should be the right start.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming table `Books(author1, ... author4, bookid, ...)` where some of the `author*` values may be null. Alternatively, an auxiliary `BookAuthors(bookid, author)` table allows an arbitrary number of authors, as well as a simpler query

This looks messy, but makes use of `UNION` (not `UNION ALL`) doing implicit `DISTINCT`.

```
select first, count(distinct second)
from (select author1 first, author2 second from Books union
      select author1, author3 from Books union
      select author1, author4 from Books union
      select author2, author1 from Books union
      select author2, author3 from Books union
      select author2, author4 from Books union
      select author3, author1 from Books union
      select author3, author2 from Books union
      select author3, author4 from Books union
      select author4, author1 from Books union
      select author4, author2 from Books union
      select author4, author3 from Books
) coauthors where first is not null and second is not null
```

Comment: thanks for the help, I should have mentioned it but I have approximately 2000+ authors, so i wont be able to write all the authors. anything more automatic? thanks